# Provide Multiple value in Kendo Dropdown DataTextField

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I want to pass two value in Kendo Dropdown DataTextField.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
          .Name("language")
          .DataTextField("LanguageName")
          .DataValueField("Id")
          .Events(e => e.Change("changelanguage"))
          .BindTo(ViewBag.languages)
          .Value(ViewBag.DefaultLanguageId)
          .Template("<img src=\"" + Url.Content("~/Images/Flags/") + "${data.CountryFlagImage}\" class="SSPLanguageDropDown\" alt=\"${data.CountryFlagImage}\" />"+ "<dl><dt><dd>${ data.LanguageName }</dd></dt></dl>"))
```

There are two value inside the kendo dropdown first is flag & another is for language. i also want to add flag at the DataTextField with the language so how can it possible to add it at there.

Comment: I tried with template but it's designed the internal drop down list css for display multiple value but i want that designed css in  selected value also with multiple value.

Comment: DropDown Item template css on selection vanishes, this feature is in queue. What we can try is, rectify our binding collection server-side and add some client-side workaround for selected item css issue. For, please provide some code. I don't know whether you are using wrappers or web scripts.

Comment: I'm Using this with the MVC & update the question with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wire up it manually:

```
@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
function changelanguage(e) {

                var selectedPrTemplate = kendo.template('<span class="k-icon k-i-clock"></span>&nbsp;#:data.LanguageName#'); //Instead of this image span, link your flag url

                var dataItem = this.dataItem();
                if (dataItem) {
                    this.span.html(selectedPrTemplate(dataItem));
                }
            }      
</script>

}
```

Comment: With Several Changes It's working very well Thanks a lot Bishnu. . . . :)

Comment: This is happened at the time of change but i need it also at the time of load the document it's not show at the time of document opens but now i can handle this but many many thanks for this bishnu.

Comment: Done with `onload()` of document also.